# How to concatenate a const char array and a char array pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, concatenation

Straight into business: I have code looking roughly like this:

```
char* assemble(int param)
{
    char* result = "Foo" << doSomething(param) << "bar";
    return result;
}
```

Now what I get is:

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [4]’ and ‘char*’ to binary ‘operator<<’
```

**Edit:**
`doSomething` returns a `char*`.

So, how do I concatenate these two?

Additional info:
Compiler: g++ 4.4.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64

Comment: Note that `<<` groups left-to-right, not right-to-left. So when you've seen `std::cout << a << b << c`, that doesn't mean "concatenate a, b and c and write the result to `std::cout`", and `<<` is not a concatenation operator. It means `(((std::cout << a) << b) << c)`, that is "write each in turn of a, b and c to `std::cout`". `operator<<` for streams returns the stream itself, precisely in order to support this chaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"Foo"` and `"Bar"` are literals, they don't have the insertion (`<<`) operator.

you instead need to use `std::string` if you want to do basic concatenation:

```
std::string assemble(int param)
{
    std::string s = "Foo";
    s += doSomething(param); //assumes doSomething returns char* or std::string
    s += "bar";
    return s;
}
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior, you are returning a **reference** to a temporary. The string will be destroyed immediately after the return statement and you will be left with a dangling reference

Answer (score 3):

Well, you're using C++, so you should be using [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/):

```
std::string assemble(int param)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Foo" << doSomething(param) << "bar";
    return ss.str();
}; // eo assemble
```

Answer (score 1):

`"Foo"` and `"bar"` have type `char const[4]`.  From the error message,
I gather that the expression `doSomething(param)` has type `char*`
(which is suspicious—it's really exceptional to have a case where
a function can reasonably return a `char*`).  None of these types
support `<<`.

You're dealing here with C style strings, which don't support
concatenation (at least not reasonably).  In C++, the concatenation
operator on strings is `+`, not `<<`, and you need C++ strings for it to
work:

```
std::string result = std::string( "Foo" ) + doSomething( param ) + "bar";
```

(Once the first argument is an `std::string`, implicit conversions will
spring into effect to convert the others.)

But I'd look at that `doSomething` function.  There's something wrong
with a function which returns `char*`.